# NgBootstrap rating rendering screen reader elements

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6, ng-bootstrap

[image]

I am trying to use NgBootstrap rating system in my project. The problem I am having is the rating system is rendering screen reader elements (see picture above).

The markup looks like this in my component

```
<ngb-rating [rate]="3"></ngb-rating>
```

and it renders like so

[image]

I am using bootstrap 4 and Angular 6.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "fancy-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.10",
    "angular2-google-map-auto-complete": "^2.0.9",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

> **What can I do to ensure that the screen reader elements do no render?**

Comment: Can you try to provide a minimal reproduce scenario? I can't see this effect on the demo page: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/examples. You can start with a forked stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pt3d3z?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: If I would _have_ to guess, I would say that Bootstrap CSS is not properly included (`sr_only` elements should be part of the DOM but hidden by CSS).